# Does anyone know the name of this Japanese font?

Tags: fonts

[![Adult Swim AcTN Logo from 2002-2012][The font is from Japan, it's from Cartoon  Networks Adult Swim block, I've looked everywhere, but i could not find it. If someone could help me identify the name of the font, I would appreciate it[image: ]]

[image: 2nd picture is from 2008]

[image: another picture from that era]

Comment: Try https://en.likefont.com/ for CJK font recognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most appropriate font [VD-LOGO JR Std U Regular](https://en.likefont.com/font/12183321/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.